# Importing data from a hyperlink on a webpage in excel using macros

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, import

I want to import some data from a website https://www.amfiindia.com/nav-history-download. On this page, there is a link "Download Complete NAV Report in Text Format" which will give me the required data. But this link is not static so I cannot use this directly in VBA to download my data. So how to download data from a hyperlink on a webpage using excel?

My approach is first getting the hyperlink in a variable then use that variable to get the data?

1. First, get the hyperlink using `getElementsByTagName` function as shown below.
2. Then use that as URL to get the data.
3. But I am getting type mismatch error while equating website which is a string with my hyperlink.

I don't know the type of href. Tried seeing in watch window showing `Variant`, tried that still error.
Kindly help me with this.

```
Sub webscraping()

Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant
Dim cellAddress As String
Dim rowNumber As Long

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument
Dim hr As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
'Dim Hra As MSHTML.IHTMLElement



Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("https://www.amfiindia.com/nav-history-download")

Do Until ie.ReadyState >= 4
        DoEvents
Loop

Set ht = ie.Document

'MsgBox ht.getElementById("navhistorydownload")

Set hr = ht.getElementsByTagName("a")(18).href


' Website to go to.
website = StrConv(hr, vbUnicode)

' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get the price from the specified element on the page.
'price = html.getElementstagName("a").Item(0).innerText

cellAddress = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address
rowNumber = Range(cellAddress).Row

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNumber + 1, 1) = response
' MsgBox rowNumber
' MsgBox cellAddress
' Output the price into a message box.
'MsgBox price

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the type then you can use

```
?typename(ht.getElementsByTagName("a")(18).href)
```

in the immediate window.

It should be a string and declared as such.

Rather than indexing into an anchor collection I would grab by css selector

```
ht.querySelector(".nav-hist-dwnld a").href
```

This specifies the parent node with class name `nav-hist-dwnld` and then asks for the first child `a` tag.

This, `website = StrConv(hr, vbUnicode)` is not required. Use the extracted `href` direct.

Comment: But I have one more doubt, Now when I am sending a request to this href I am getting "Bad Request" instead of the text on-page. The response variable is showing bad request not the data on that site. Please help me with this!

Comment: You may need to add appropriate headers. Use the browser network tab to see what headers were sent when you refresh the page with F5

Comment: Thank you @QHarr, I checked the headers and I conctenated it with the hyperlink like this: ```mtbl = objIE.document.querySelector(".nav-hist-dwnld a").href Header = "https://www.amfiindia.com" website = Header & mtbl ```Now I am not getting the bad request error but it is saying a new error ```The system cannot locate the resource specified . ```